# How to convert a prefix+domain name to a directory/prefix in EKS(kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have a Route53 and EKS environment.

I have written several domain names in EKS ingress-controller, and now I need to access each directory using URLs.

If you have a domain name, "example.com", and it has a prefix, you want to treat the prefix as a directory after the domain name.
(ex:main.example.com -> example.com/main)
(ex:settings.example.com -> example.com/settings)

In other words, if you enter "main.example.com" in your browser's URL, it will access the pod example.com/main that is being routed.

I'm spending a lot of working hours on this issue.
Do you know the solution?

This is part of my "ingress.yaml".

```
enter code here
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "ingress"
  namespace: "public"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: 
      '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: ****secret****
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  server {
    location / {
      server_name ~^(?<name>[\w-]+)\.example\.com$;
      proxy_pass http://example.com/$name;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  }
labels:
  app: develop-app
spec:
 rules:
   - host: main.example.com
     http:
      paths:
       - path: /*
         backend:
           serviceName: "hook"
           servicePort: 8080
   - host: settings.example.com
     http:
      paths:
       - path: /*
         backend:
           serviceName: "hook"
           servicePort: 8080
   - host: example.com
     http:
      paths:
       - path: /*
         backend:
           serviceName: "hook"
           servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: For example, I tried to give it a full name like this
server_name "main\.example\.com";
proxy_pass http://example/main;
However, I am wondering why when I enter "http://main.example.com" in the URL, it is not treated as "http://example.com/main".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update base on your feedback, what you may be looking for is using nginx server block rather than k8s ingress rules:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ...
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      server {
        location / {
          server_name ~^(?<name>[\w-]+)\.example\.com$;
          proxy_pass http://<your k8s service>/$name;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
      }
spec:
  rules:
  - host: main.example.com
  - host: setting.example.com
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.

The problem has not been completely solved, but thanks to you I see a path to the end.

When "example.com" is set to the lowest priority, there is still a problem with the connection.
However, I think this is because the destination is different for "example.com" and EC2 is the destination.

Comment: Hmmm
Only when I entered "example.com/main" into the URL, it returns the correct response.

How do I connect to /main in the directory under example.com (example pod) when that URL is entered?

Comment: Ingress rule does not do this, you will need to dive into nginx server block. The updated answer will give you the **idea**.

Comment: Thank you for your generous follow-up.

As you said, I tried the code you suggested, but it didn't work.
Is "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet" not working properly, or is it due to a conflict with another annotation?

I've added a piece of code to the question.

Comment: Note `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb` does not support what you want to do. You need to use [ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) in order to use nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/[server-snippet](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/).